# "Not a GROUP BY expression" error when using custom function calls in Factored Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, common-table-expression

Let's assume I have these tables (ignore that they are essentially the same, actual setup is more complex than this):

```
create table inbound (
    id number(19,0) not null,
    created_on timestamp(6),
    place_id number(19,0),
    qty_amount float(126),

    constraint "inbound_pk" primary key (id),
    constraint "inbound_place_FK" foreign key (place_id)
        references place (id) on delete cascade 
);

create table outbound (
    id number(19,0) not null,
    created_on timestamp(6),
    place_id number(19,0),
    qty_amount float(126),

    constraint "outbound_pk" primary key (id),
    constraint "outbound_place_FK" foreign key (place_id)
        references place (id) on delete cascade 
)
```

Then, I have this query:

```
with aligned_in (start_date, place_id, total) as (
    select
        get_week_start(place_id, created_on) start_date,
        place_id,
        sum(qty_amount) total
    from inbound
    where <....>
    group by
        get_week_start(place_id, created_on), place_id
),
aligned_out (start_date, place_id, total) as (
    select
        get_week_start(place_id, created_on) start_date,
        place_id,
        sum(qty_amount) total
    from outbound
    where <....>
    group by get_week_start(place_id, created_on), place_id
)

select
   start_date,
   place_id,
   aligned_in.total total_in,
   aligned_out.total total_out
from aligned_in
  left outer join aligned_out using(place_id, start_date)
```

For some reason, this query, when executed on Oracle 12.2.0.1.0, throws out a

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

error with line pointing at line with a call to `get_week_start`.

While fiddling with it, I've also discovered the following:

- The subqueries for `aligned_in` and `aligned_out` can be run completely fine by themselves
- Removing call to `get_week_start` from the subqueries' projection fixes it - the group by clause without this call in projection works (but obviously changes a lot about how this query written and executes)
- (The thing which I'm most confused about) This exact query without any alterations runs completely fine on Oracle 11.2.0.2.0
- Most info on `ORA-00979` is not very useful because it doesn't appear applicable at all to my query

Here, the `get_week_start` is a pretty simple function to find out what the start of a business week would be at a given `Place` (this is customer's data). Due to how it's defined, this function is not deterministic. However, I did run into suggestions that such functions should be marked deterministic, and did try doing that just to see what happens - and that did not help.

So, why is this happening?

What changed beween versions 11.2.0 and 12.2.0 that caused this? Am I missing some configuration option? Can this be fixed without rewriting the query?

**Edit**:

Sample version of `get_week_start` as requested in comments:

```
create function get_week_start(place_id number, week_day date)
    return date
as
    start_date date;
begin
    begin
        select
            trunc(next_day(week_day, o.business_week_start)) - 7
                into start_date
        from place
            inner join place_owner o on o.id = place.owner_id
        where place.id = place_id;

        return stat_date;
    exception
    when others then return null;
    end;
end get_week_start;
```

Sample tables for `place` and `place_owner`:

```
create table place_owner (
    id number(19,0) not null,
    name varchar2(255) not null,
    business_week_start varchar2(64) not null,

    constraint "place_owner_pk" primary key (id)
);

create table place (
    id number(19, 0) not null,
    name varchar2(255) not null,
    owner_id number(19,0) not null,

    constraint "place_pk" primary key (id),
    constraint "place_unq" unique (owner_id, name),
    constraint "place_owner_fk" foreign key (owner_id)
        references place_owner (id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: It might be caused by whether or not the function is declared as `DETERMINISTIC`.  You should be able to fix this by putting the function call in a subquery.

Comment: So what does `get_week_start` do? Is that an aggregate function?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, as I said, I tried marking the function `deterministic`, that didn't seem to help. Also, did they made requirement to be deterministic stricter in 12?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it's a select statement inside the function, actually. Generally I can expect that it would return same result for the arguments if called in _readonly_ transaction, but I doubt that makes the function deterministic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, just confirmed with [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/DETERMINISTIC-clause.html): `deterministic` function may not access the database, so that makes `get_week_start` a non-deterministic function. Is that the problem then?

Comment: A working simplified example would help a lot. I made one with a single table and a dummy function and it worked for me in 12.2.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, unfortunately, I can't ensure that any example I'm giving would be a [mcve] here, because I'm not sure what causes my problem to reproduce. Please try replacing body of your dummy function with a call to some other table. The more I'm looking into this the more I'm thinking that it's the function that is the problem.

Comment: I had the function `select p_created_at + p_place_id + count(*) into l_date from inbound;` and return that. Still fine. I recommend creating a simplified example from scratch as a diagnostic exercise.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, definitely reproduced with pretty much what I had in question. Seems like you selecting from the `inbound` table is not enough to make this reproducible, you do need a `places` and `place_owner` table. I'll add that as well.

Comment: If you could make sure the DDL runs without errors that would be great. The samples above have some typos (missing comma, double-quotes). Probably no data is needed as it appears to be a syntax issue.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, do note that I'm trying to make this minimal. Actual code is a lot more involved and has a lot more logic than I'm comfortable sharing for this question. It's definitely not a syntax issue, as we had this same code going for some time already, and it only pretty much became a problem after upgrade to Oracle 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` (Oracle 12c):

```
with aligned_in (start_date, place_id, total) as (
    select
        s.start_date,
        place_id,
        sum(qty_amount) total
    from inbound
    cross apply (SELECT get_week_start(place_id, created_at) AS start_date 
                FROM dual) s 
    where <....>
    group by
         s.start_date, place_id
),
...
```

Another approach:

```
with aligned_in (start_date, place_id, total) as (
    SELECT start_date,
           place_id,
           sum(qty_amount) total
    FROM (select get_week_start(place_id, created_at) AS  start_date,
                 place_id,
                 qty_amount
           from inbound
           where <....>) sub
    group by start_date, place_id
),  
-- ...
```

Comment: It's looks to be a solution, but unfortunately we need compatibility with Oracle 11, so I can't use this for now.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Please try second approach on both versions. If it won't help then you could add another CTE + hint /*+materialize*/

Comment: Yes, the second one I've been thinking of doing as well. That approach definitely works, but in actual query that would constitute a sizeable change, which we are trying to avoid. I'll wait to see if there would be any other approaches outlined (or maybe straignt up a link to an Oracle bug, because right now it definitely looks like one to me).

Comment: Also, just tried the cross apply thingy on 12c instance, and it still produces the same error. Looks like whatever part of the query compiler is being triggered, it's pretty smart at what it does.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Please check on 12c `cross apply (SELECT (SELECT get_week_start(place_id, created_at)  FROM dual)AS start_date 
                FROM dual) s`

Comment: No, same thing. I may be affected by query optimizer at this point which peels off extra `select from dual`s, so adding more is unlikely to help.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov One way is to add expression like `WHERE 2 = 1+1` but I doubt it will change anything in this case.